# Implementing the audio_recorder.dart in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I only have hours of experience and am trying to implement this:

https://github.com/ZaraclaJ/audio_recorder

I am currently piggybacking of Android Studio's example (increment counter).

However I am having trouble with the following line:

AudioRecorder.start(path: _controller.text, audioOutputFormat: AudioOutputFormat.AAC);

What is "path: _controller.text" supposed to be?

Comment: Here's the full code of that example. https://github.com/ZaraclaJ/audio_recorder/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart